# django: FooSearchListView' object has no attribute 'object_list'

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am using Django 3.2 and django-taggit 1.4

I have a model Foo defined like this:

#### /path/to/myapp/models.py

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    story = models.CharField()
    caption = models.CharField()
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

I am trying to write a search for Foo objects matching one or more tags, using CBV.

Here is my code:

#### /path/to/myapp/views.py

```
class FooSearchListView(ListView):
    model = Foo
    slug_field = 'query'
    context_object_name = 'foo_list'
    paginate_by = 3


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    
        query_original = request.POST.get('search_terms', None)
        page = request.POST.get('page', 1)
 
        q_filter = Q()

        if query_original:
            keywords = [x.strip() for x in query_original.lower().split(',')]

            title_match = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(title__icontains=word) for word in keywords))
            story_match = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(story__icontains=word) for word in keywords))
            captions_match = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(caption__icontains=word) for word in keywords))             
            tags_match = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(tags__name__icontains=word) for word in keywords))

            q_filter = title_match | story_match | captions_match | tags_match 
    
        foos = Foo.objects.filter(q_filter).distinct().order_by('-date_added')


        context = self.get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)       
        context['keywords'] = keywords

        return render(request, 'search_items.html', context=context)
```

#### /path/to/my/app/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ...         
    path('search/', FooSearchListView.as_view(), name='foo-search'),     
    # ...

]
```

I don't like the way I have structured the code, because I am not able to override methods like `get_queryset()`, etc. and all of the logic is just in the `post()` method - because searches are deliberately done on only POSTS.

I have two issues with the code above:

1. When I try a search in the browser, I get the error message: FooSearchListView' object has no attribute 'object_list'
2. Pagination does not work

How do I resolve these issues?

**[[ Edit ]]**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/my/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/path/to/my/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/path/to/my/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/my/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/my/project/foo/views.py", line 185, in post
    context = self.get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/my/project/foo/views.py", line 159, in get_context_data
    context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/my/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py", line 115, in get_context_data
    queryset = object_list if object_list is not None else self.object_list

Exception Type: AttributeError at /foo/search/
Exception Value: 'FoooSearchListView' object has no attribute 'object_list'
```

Comment: I don't see any reason you can't override `get_queryset`, and you can remove `get_context_data` because it's not doing anything. Can you include the full stacktrace for the `object_list` error? It's unclear where that'd be happening.

Comment: @markwalker_ does `get_queryset()` also get invoked for POST requests?. It would be very useful if there was a MRO cheatsheet for CBVs so that one can at least work out the order in which methods are being invoked (or if even they are being invoked at all). Yes, the `get_context_data()` method insn't doing anything useful in the snippet I posted. I'll remove it.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli a `ListView` does not have a builtin implementation for `post` and even if it did you override it in your code, hence `get_queryset` is not called in your implementation.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli I think you'll enjoy making a bookmark out of this; http://ccbv.co.uk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListView` inherits from `MultipleObjectMixin` down the line. `MultipleObjectMixin` overrides the method `get_context_data` and has the following [line [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f5dccbafb957841d0867f0b153d7f7123f0ec83d/django/views/generic/list.py#L115):

> ```py
> queryset = object_list if object_list is not None else self.object_list
> ```

The problem is you have overriden `post` for your view and are calling `get_context_data` without ever setting `self.object_list` (which the `get` method sets in its implementation) hence you get the error. Hence you need to set it's value in your `post` method:

```py
self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
context = self.get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or after looking at your implementation a bit more it seems you want to perform some filtering and use that as your queryset. You can try something like follows if that is so:

```py
class FooSearchListView(ListView):
    model = Foo
    slug_field = 'query'
    context_object_name = 'foo_list'
    paginate_by = 3
    
    def filter_queryset(self, queryset=None):
        if queryset is None:
            queryset = self.get_queryset()
        query_original = self.request.POST.get('search_terms', None)
        page = self.request.POST.get('page', 1)
        q_filter = Q()

        if query_original:
            keywords = [x.strip() for x in query_original.lower().split(',')]

            title_match = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(title__icontains=word) for word in keywords))
            story_match = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(story__icontains=word) for word in keywords))
            captions_match = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(caption__icontains=word) for word in keywords))             
            tags_match = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(tags__name__icontains=word) for word in keywords))

            q_filter = title_match | story_match | captions_match | tags_match
        return queryset.filter(q_filter).distinct().order_by('-date_added')
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object_list = self.filter_queryset(queryset=self.get_queryset())
        context = self.get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)       
        context['keywords'] = keywords

        return render(request, 'search_items.html', context=context)
```

Comment: Abdul to the rescue again! :)  do I need to override the `get_queryset()` method? It seems that is where most of the logic in my `post()` method should be - however, I only want to accept POST requests for search. How do I square that circle?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli check my edit, you might also want to have a look at the package [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#) if you want to filter things easily (Filtering becomes quite easy like forms with it)